# is it possible to have two different folders to mount on the same filestore instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, nfs, google-cloud-filestore

I am trying to connect a filestore instance to my GKE cluster. I have two deployments on my GKE cluster, writing to two separate volume claims. What i want to know is:

- is it possible for me to have a central nfs with my one google filestore instance?
- how can i make folders inside the filestore instance and have my pods talk to it without interference?

The other option i see is i create two different filestores - this seems to solve my problem, but I am currently setting up my cluster architecture and it seems like a huge waste of resources (I have ~ 1TB data, but my pods use around 50GB each - so i was thinking of partitioning, but the GCP docs are too cryptic)

Any other suggestions to what i am trying to achieve is also welcome :)

Comment: Have you try this link [Accessing file shares from Google Kubernetes Engine clusters](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares#create_a_persistent_volume_claim).

Comment: tried it, did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filestore volumes support ReadWriteMany so you can mount the same PV on multiple pods for write access.  You'd create a single PersistentVolumeClaim with accessModes set to ReadWriteMany:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: sharedpvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: standard-rwx
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Ti
```

and then mount it in each of your deployments

```
volumes:
  - name: shared
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: sharedpvc
```

So the same Filestore instance is now mounted on the pods/deployments, but you still need to use your own mechanism to ensure pods don't clobber each other's data.  There are two options here I'd consider:

- use a separate prefix for all files written for each deployment
- create a directory within the volume for each deployment

You can't create separate partitions and you can't limit the storage size for each deployment.  But this way you can have multiple pods writing to the same instance rather than creating multiple 1TB instances.

Comment: yep, nice - i just solved it today with what you proposed - i also managed to make the sub directories part work by using a bastion vm from gce

Comment: I have multiple folders within a Filestore, one for each Pod. I want to mount a single folder to a single Pod at location `/mnt/data`? Is this possible? Say `filestore/pod1` gets mounted at `/mnt/data` for pod1 and `filestore/pod2` folder gets mounted at `/mnt/data` in pod2.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Gari's answer, the reason why it's not possible to do partitioning:

Just to clarify, Google Cloud Filestore is an NFS server. Therefore, it is not "partitioned" (only [block devices](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/data-storage/file-block-object-storage#what-is-block-storage) are), rather it has a concept of "export shares" and each share can be mounted by one or more clients. When mounted, the share appears as a single filesystem directory to the client.

Your options are:

1. use a single share, attach it as a PV in Kubernetes, then create directories in that single share to match their Pod structure (Gari's answer); or
2. use multiple share, each corresponding to a group of Pods or services, and attach each share to K8s as a different PV (not ideal based on your use case).

The key point here is: all Filestore shares are NFS exports so they can be seen from K8s as PVs of the relevant kind.